# do filter when user press enter button in angular js grid

Tags: angularjs

// this filter api called when i filter any text in filter box of the grid but i have to filter a text when user press a enter button after type a text on filter box.

```
    $scope.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, function() {
        var grid = this.grid;
        $scope.getPage(paginationOptions.pageNumber, paginationOptions.pageSize, null, null, grid.columns[1].filters[0].term, grid.columns[2].filters[0].term, grid.columns[3].filters[0].term, grid.columns[4].filters[0].term);
    });
```

Comment: Could you provide additional code and context as to what you are attempting to do?

Comment: there is no other code for this filter i just made one function call $scope.getPage() which i already called from this filter change api  in which i get the json response from server side and display data on the grid.
Please provide any code that if i press enter button after typing a text on filter box then and only then filter will work.